MAUI: Pending exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (15 ... 15) ends beyond length 12
I am getting below exception for an Entry's TextChangedEventArgs event.

Pending exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (15 ... 15) ends beyond length 12
(Throwable with no stack trace)
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodA called with pending exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (15 ... 15) ends beyond length 12
(Throwable with no stack trace)
in call to CallObjectMethodA
from void crc6477f0d89a9cfd64b1.EntryRendererBase_1.n_onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int)

Phone number is inputting on the Entry and using TextChangedEventArgs I am formating it based on the count code. For eg: if the phone number starts with +1, I will format the text like +1 123 123 1234. the phone number starts with +91, I will format the text like +1 12345 12345. If no code, I will show like 123 123 1234.
I am facing the above exception when copy paste the phone number starts with +91. Below is the code:
public async void CallCustomersList(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        int currentLength = args.NewTextValue.Length;
        if (currentLength == 0)
        {
            //do some actions
        }
        else
        {
            var text = SearchEntry.Text;
            if(IsDigitsOnly(text.Replace(" ","")) || text.Contains("+"))
            {
                if (text.Length != 0)
                {
                    text = RemoveSpecialCharacter(text, SearchEntry);
                    string prefix = SearchEntry.Text.Substring(0, 2);
                    string indPrefix = SearchEntry.Text.Substring(0, 3);
                    if (text.StartsWith("+1"))
                    {
                        if (text.Length > 8)
                        {
                            isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 2) + " " + text.Substring(2, 3) + " " + text.Substring(5, 3) + " " + text.Substring(8);
                        }
                        else if (text.Length > 5)
                        {
                            isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 2) + " " + text.Substring(2, 3) + " " + text.Substring(5);
                        }
                        else if (text.Length > 2)
                        {
                            isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 2) + " " + text.Substring(2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SearchEntry.Text = text;
                        }
                        SearchEntry.MaxLength = 15;
                    }
                    else if(text.StartsWith("+91"))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("text:>>" + text);
                        Debug.WriteLine("length:>>" + text.Length);
                        isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                        if (text.Length > 8)
                        {
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 3) + " " + text.Substring(3, 5) + " " + text.Substring(8);
                        }
                        else if (text.Length > 3)
                        {
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 3) + " " + text.Substring(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SearchEntry.Text = text;
                        }
                        SearchEntry.MaxLength = 15;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (text.Length > 6)
                        {
                            isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 3) + " " + text.Substring(3, 3) + " " + text.Substring(6);
                        }
                        else if (text.Length > 3)
                        {
                            isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = true;
                            SearchEntry.Text = text.Substring(0, 3) + " " + text.Substring(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SearchEntry.Text = text;
                        }
                        SearchEntry.MaxLength = 12;
                    }
                    SearchEntry.CursorPosition = SearchEntry.Text.Length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SearchEntry.MaxLength = 100;
            }
            if (IsDigitsOnly(text.Replace(" ", "")) || text.Contains("+"))
            {
                if (args.NewTextValue.Contains("+1"))
                {
                    Preferences.Default.Set("keyword", args.NewTextValue.Replace(" ", "").Remove(0,2));
                }
                else
                {
                    Preferences.Default.Set("keyword", args.NewTextValue.Replace(" ", ""));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted)
                {
                    SearchEntry.Text = args.NewTextValue.Replace(" ", "");
                    Preferences.Default.Set("keyword", SearchEntry.Text);
                    isUsPhoneNumberFormatStarted = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Preferences.Default.Set("keyword", args.NewTextValue);
                }
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("keyword:>>" + Preferences.Default.Get("keyword", ""));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception123:>" + e);
    }
}

public string RemoveSpecialCharacter(string phoneNumber, Entry SelectedEntry)
{
    string[] chars = new string[] { ",", " ", ".", "/", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "'", "\"", ";", "_", "(", ")", ":", "|", "[", "]", "-" };
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (phoneNumber.Contains(chars[i]))
        {
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(chars[i], "");
        }
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}

bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

I used the same codes and try to recreate this issue on a demo project, but on that it is working fine. If we type or paste the phone number it is working as expected. But on the working project, I am facing the above exception.
By checking the code and exception can anyone suggest any suggestions?

I tested the code you provided and it works well. You say that on your working project you are facing the exception. I find the similar issue on GitHub: Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 'setSpan ( ... ) ends beyond length #19689. It shows that new version sloved the question. This explains why the exception no longer exists in a new project.

@JianweiSun-MSFT What packages do I need to update to resolve this issue?

It should be the version of MAUI.

@JianweiSun-MSFT You mean from .net 7 to .net 8?

Your working project is net 7?

@JianweiSun-MSFT Yes, it is .net 7

You can update the project to net 8. The issue on GitHub shows that new version sloved the question. You can try it.

@JianweiSun-MSFT I have converted the project to .net 8 but I am facing another issue now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78895708/unable-to-install-app-from-visual-studio-error-detecting-existing-process

You mean this issue has been solved by updating the version of porject, but for now face another issue?

@JianweiSun-MSFT I updated the project .net 8, but I can't test the issue fix since the app is breaking when start loading. That issue is raised as a new ticket

Yes, I have seen the new ticket you post, and also notice that my colleague is dealing with it. For now, a simple and crude way to do it is: Move the code of current project into a new .net8 project.

Well, as answer:
About this issue:

MAUI: Pending exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (15 ... 15) ends beyond length 12

Updating the version of .NET from .net 7 to .net 8 can solve it. For more information can refer to the issue on MAUI GitHub: Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 'setSpan ( ... ) ends beyond length #19689.
