Unable to Install App from Visual Studio – Error: Detecting existing process
I'm having trouble installing my MAUI app directly from Visual Studio. Whenever I try to install it, I encounter errors, and the app breaks during the installation process.
Development Environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.11.0 Preview 7.0
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.9.0 Preview 2.1
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.10.5

Error Message:
12:57:53:294    Start debugging Android application ...
12:57:53:294    Forwarding debugger port 8809
12:57:53:294    Detecting existing process
12:57:54:063    > am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.appname/crc64504875b33ff43b35.MainActivity"
12:57:54:386    > Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.companyname.appname/crc64504875b33ff43b35.MainActivity }

How can I resolve this issue?
Update
I have created a sample project and uploaded it here.
I have created a sample project using GitHub and uploaded it here.

Are you installing the app on an emulator or real device?

That doesn't look like an error message. Is this all that is printed to the output?

@PMF Yes only this is printed on the output message, nothing else is there

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I am trying on real device

@MatthewPans 1. You can try to uninstall the app from the device and clear the cache data. Then re-install the project. If it doesn't work, try another emulator or device to install the app. 2. Tick Fast deployment option under Android--> Options.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I tried the suggestion you provided, but it didn't work.

@MatthewPans How can we reproduce the issue, can you help create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and edit it to your post?

@Alexandar May - MSFT Sorry for the late response. We have updated the question with demo project. Could you please check?

@MatthewPans Better to provide the demo using GitHub if possible.

@Alexandar May - MSFT We have updated the question with demo project using GitHub. Could you please check?

To fix the issue, please right click the project --> select Properties --> find Fast deployment in Android option.
After unticking the Fast deployment option, the MAUI app can run on the device without issue.
